# how do i access both my file using sys.argv?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, sys

I sent two files on sys path.

Below is my code:

```
arr = [filename1.csv,filename2.csv]

for i in arr:
  sys.stdout.write(i + '\n')
```

but when I try to access it with sys.argv[1:], it only returns me last file i.e. filename2.csv, I don't know why, help me out here.

Comment: It is most likely due to the `\n`, you should use a space and only add a `\n` at the very end.
But we don't see enough of your code to be sure...

Comment: if i am not using \n then my output is like sys.argv = ['pythonfile.py', 'filename1.csvfilename2'] , i want this to return as third argument and not two arguments combined

Comment: my code writes these two files to a gcs path and then accesses these two files to send in an email as an attachment

Comment: You may want to try using a space instead: `' '`

Answer (score -1):

This is because index start with 0 in Python, you should try sys.argv[0:].

Comment: `sys.argv[0]` is the name of the executable. The first command line argument is at `sys.argv[1]`. The OP is using `sys.argv` correctly. This would be using `sys.argv` incorrectly.

Comment: No Jeremy, sys.argv[0:] is by default your python script file